# Speed up executemany query for inserting data into MySQL database from Python

Tags: python, mysql, sql-insert, executemany

I have the following (sample) set of data that I'm trying to insert into a MySQL database from Python:

```
matchups_data = [('Davis Love III', 1706, 1, -2.0, 124.0),
 ('Davis Love III', 1706, 2, -4.0, 22.0),
 ('Davis Love III', 1706, 3, 3.0, 135.0),
 ('Davis Love III', 1706, 4, 2.0, 87.0),
 ('Davis Love III', 1706, 5, 1.0, 68.0),
 ('Davis Love III', 1706, 6, 1.0, 118.0),
 ('Davis Love III', 1706, 7, 0.0, 103.0),
 ('Davis Love III', 1706, 8, -3.0, 35.0),
 ('Davis Love III', 1706, 9, -1.0, 131.0),
 ('Davis Love III', 1706, 10, 0.0, 100.0)]
```

The actual set of data I'm inserting is approximately 1.4 million rows and when I use the below query to insert it into my database is more time than I would expect (10+ minutes).

```
import mysql.connector

db = mysql.connector.connect(
host = db_host,
user = un,
password = pw,
database = 'golfstaging')

cursor = db.cursor()

matchups_insert_query = """
INSERT INTO MatchupSimResults (PlayerName, PlayerID, SimNum, R1Score, TourneyRank)
values(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)
"""

matchups_data = list(zip(sim_results['player_name'], sim_results['player_id'],
                        sim_results['sim'], sim_results['R1'], sim_results['tourney_rank']))

cursor.executemany(matchups_insert_query, matchups_data)
db.commit()
```

Is there something I can be doing differently - either with the executemany function or with the dataset - to speed this up?

Comment: Are you using psycopg by chance?

Comment: @Nathan I am not, I'm using mysql.connector

Comment: Can you add the relevant import statements and a link to the package you are using to your question? It will help people help you.

Comment: have you thought about normalizing your data?

Comment: @nbk I'm not sure what you mean by that, so no

Comment: your first two coumn have the same data 'Davis Love III', 1706  if you save those data in a separate table, you reduce the data to a minimuml. less data more speed

Comment: Better data-loading performance usually involves using [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) instead of INSERT. See my presentation [Load Data Fast!](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/load-data-fast)